# ember acceptance tests wait helpers

Tags: ember.js, acceptance-testing

I am writing acceptance tests for my ember app and one of the component take user input and validates credentials after which user can click continue and proceed ahead. The problem I am facing is as soon as tests fill in the input fields, then it clicks on the next button and andThen helper is not inducing sufficient wait or pause because of which test fails as I am setting some property once validation is completed.

Is there a way to induce delay while writing acceptance tests apart from andThen.

Comment: In newer ember versions, syntax has changed: https://guides.emberjs.com/release/testing/acceptance/ 
can you try with the new `await fillIn('.my-input')` and `await click('.my-button')`?
sometimes the `await settled()` test helper its nice to wait for timeouts and animations...

Comment: It does not work for me, it does not know about await helper. Is there any specific import needed?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the version of Ember you might be using *(any version pre v3.0 according to the guides)* the [ember-maybe-import-regenerator](https://github.com/machty/ember-maybe-import-regenerator) addon may be the best option. This addon will allow you to use `async / await` within your app code and test code, which should provide you the alternative from `andThen` that you require. Ember v3.0  provides test helpers that support `async / await`.

Here is a GitHubGist that provides further insight: [async/await in ember tests](https://gist.github.com/caseywatts/7c01654f74fbe402dfaadfa144965adb)

Answer (score 1):

I found another way to temporarily pause an Ember Qunit test for a specific timeframe. I needed this in `ember-cli` 3.10.1 and `ember-cli-qunit` 4.4.0, which includes `ember-test-helpers`. I'm already using the new async `await click()` syntax.

The problem I had was `await waitFor()` wouldn't work for my test because another addon in my app responded to the `await click()` event, then took an unknown amount of time to process, then re-rendered, removing content instead of inserting it. The next `assert` in my code would fail when it ran before the addon re-rendered. What I needed was something much closer to a straightforward `setTimeout()`, because I didn't have a DOM selector I could pass to `await waitFor()` since the DOM nodes were actually disappearing instead of being rendered. Here is my workaround:

```
setTimeout(() => {this.resumeTest()}, 1000); // wait for ember-changeset-validations to update, removing invalid input message
await pauseTest();
```

This uses `setTimeout()` with an arrow function to maintain scope and wait 1s, then calls `this.resumeTest()`. The `resumeTest()` resolves the `await pauseTest()` line, resuming the test code after this section. In effect, these two lines amount to a 1s temporary pause in the ember test execution.

This has worked perfectly for my tests where a DOM node or other content is being destroyed, which is the opposite of what `await waitFor()` can handle.

Be sure to include the `pauseTest` fn in your import statement:

```
import { pauseTest } from '@ember/test-helpers';
```